# Querying input text with javascript and checking for a value does not work

Tags: javascript, string, input, type-conversion, numbers

I would like to query an input field with Javascript and from a value of over 20 a button should be released. Javascript works too. Unfortunately, if I enter the number with a comma instead of a period, it no longer works.

```js
var checkEmpty_ek = document.querySelector('#ek');
checkEmpty_ek.addEventListener('input', function() {
  if (checkEmpty_ek.value >= 20) {
    document.getElementById("neuerbuttonspeichern").disabled = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("neuerbuttonspeichern").disabled = true;
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="ek" name="ek" value="$ek">
<input type="button" id="neuerbuttonspeichern" value="Send" />
```

Comment: Couldn't you just remove the comma from value and make the number uniform for the conditional?

Comment: You would then have to deal with what can enter the input

Comment: I made you a snippet.

Comment: You didn't give us a lot of information, you didn't say for example what this script is for, who you are going to use and what you really want to do. For example, do you just want the script to be able to correctly interpret that number with a comma? Or do you want to prevent the user from being able to put a comma number in the input?

Answer (score 1):

Try: `let inputValue = Number(checkEmpty_ek.value.replace(",","."));` inside function.

And then check: `(inputValue >= 20)`

It is not the most elegant solution, but it will resolve if the user types the number with a comma or with letters and special characters.

Bye.

Answer (score 0):

Use type =  number

```js
var checkEmpty_ek = document.querySelector('#ek');
checkEmpty_ek.addEventListener('input', function() {
  document.getElementById("neuerbuttonspeichern").disabled = checkEmpty_ek.value < 20;
});
```

```html
$ek<input type="number" id="ek" name="ek" value="0">
<input type="button" id="neuerbuttonspeichern" value="Send" disabled />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Number(checkEmpty_ek.value.replace(/,/g, '')) >= 20) {
{ 
     document.getElementById("neuerbuttonspeichern").disabled = false;
} else 
{
     document.getElementById("neuerbuttonspeichern").disabled = true;
});
```

If you are just looking to remove any potential commas from the input, this will do it.  But like someone else commented, we aren't really familiar with your user interaction expectations.  Chances are, you'll be filtering out more than commas.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the comma with the dot.

```
Number(checkEmpty_ek.value.replace(",",".")) 

Number ("20.") === 20
```

```js
var checkEmpty_ek = document.querySelector('#ek');
checkEmpty_ek.addEventListener('input', function() {
console.log(checkEmpty_ek.value)
  if (Number(checkEmpty_ek.value.replace(",",".")) >= 20) {
    document.getElementById("neuerbuttonspeichern").disabled = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("neuerbuttonspeichern").disabled = true;
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="ek" name="ek" value="">
<input type="button" id="neuerbuttonspeichern" value="Send" />
```